# My TextView not support this (') character

Tags: java, android, textview

I just fetched some data from `JSon` and listed into my Listview. It's fetching properly. But, in my listview's `'` character didn't support there? What'll i do for this? But, in basically it's supports when, we use like this -

```
TextView titletv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
titletv.setText("I'm in critical situation");
```

It's displaying fine when we set that character by above code. Otherwise, it won't supports.

**Update**

In my `JSON` getting time i've the text like this -

```
Per capita income likely to cross Rs 60,000 in â11-12
```

See in above line `â` Character only disturbed me. But, this actual value is nothing but `'` only.

My Actual result is -

```
Per capita income likely to cross Rs 60,000 in ’11-12
```

And, my Screenshot is here -

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: What is the response from JSon and what is displayed with the json value?

Comment: Have you tried to escape? use \'

Comment: @Shaiful Yes, it's response with the original character of json. But, it'll not print into listview

Comment: @JordiCoscolla `Escape` use \ How?

Comment: What is the printed value in listview?

Comment: I mean the result of the Value @Shaiful

Comment: Put a screenshot of the listview and also put the json string you've get.

Comment: `Per capita income likely to cross Rs 60,000 in â11-12` this is only getting for me in Json @Shaiful

Comment: all you nee is to change your language. because that latter is not from English Alphabet.

Comment: @Lucifer How can i change that latter to English Alphabet.

Comment: well AFAIK, you can not change a single latter with different language. But you try other way, this could be a last option, just diplay its image rather than text.

Comment: Thank you all of you who've responsed me. I've got the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to escape the value `'` to have `\'`.
You can do this:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replace("'","\'");
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
titletv.setText(jsonString);
```

Cheers.

**EDIT**

As we discuss in the comments the problem was that the encoding was ANSI instead of UTF-8.

Comment: The text you posted is the JSON itself or the way it's displayed ?

Comment: Json itself. And, it's displayed like above screenshot

Comment: What is the encoding of the JSON?

Comment: ISO only i've used in my `InputStreamReader`

Comment: Yes, it's working now dude. If i use `UTF-8` means, it'll show the original value and also no need of `replace` method. Thanks dude. Thanks

Comment: Now, tell me please. What'll i use `ANSI` or `UTF-8`

Comment: You have to use the same encoding than the response you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You should just write

```
titletv.setText("I\'m in critical situation");
```